# how to create a validation to check image type in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, web, file-upload, frontend

can someone tell me how to create a method to check the image type?

I'm creating an image component in which only the following types will be accepted
[JPEG GIF, including animated GIFs, PNG SVG,BMP]

Comment: Hi, can you explain more ? You are creating a component which does what exactly ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it in Angular, but in native JS you can get the file type as an attribute of the file object.

I think there will be something similar in Angular.

```
const onchange = (event) => {
    const filetype = event.target.files[0].type;
    console.log(filetype);
}
```

or more general:

```
const elem = document.getElementById('your-file-input');
console.log(elem.files[0].type);
```

This will log something like "image/png" or "application/pdf" which you then can check.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from the question that you need to accept only certain file types, you can easily do it in html as your input type will be file to accept a file so use accept attribute of input type file where you can pass the extensions you need to support.
Refere w3school tutorials -
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp

```html
<input type="file" id="img" name="img" accept="image/*">
```